# how to print a table of even squares?

Tags: c

This program prompts the user a number and then outputs a table of even squares ranging from 2 to the number.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i, n;

  puts(This program prints a table of even squares.);
  printf("Enter range of the squares square: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for (i = 2; i * i <= n; i += 2)
    printf("%d\n", i * i);

  return 0;
}
```

for example:

> ```
> Enter range of the squares: 123
>          2         4
>          4        16
>          6        36
>          8        64
>         10       100
> ```

The problem is did not print **121** (which is **11 * 11**). I am new to C and not really good in using loops. Please help!

Comment: what did it print out then?

Comment: Why should you print 11*11? 11 is not even.

Comment: Sorry I just like Haskell more. Sorry for this error.

Comment: Note: `printf("%d\n", i * i);` does not print `"         2         4"`.  Best to post true code and true I/O.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i = 2; i * i <= n; i += 2)
```

You're starting at 2 and incrementing by 2. `i` will never be 11.